# How does a while loop inside a for loop work?

Tags: java, loops

Sorry for the basic question. But does the code finish executing the inner while loop and then update the count in the outer for loop? or does it perform each variable update in an alternating fashion?

example:

```
int j= 1;
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
{

   while(i <3)
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some `System.out.println()` statements in there and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will enter the for loop first when i = 0. Immediately after it will enter the while loop and continue running indefinitely as i will always be 0 and therefore < 3. You perhaps need to deal with j in the break condition of inner loop for avoiding an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never break out of that inner while loop unless you deal with the 'i' variable inside that loop. Infinite loop shall occur.

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of i is 0. Then it starts executing while loop. Test is i < 3 what evaluates to true for i = 0.

```
while(true){
  j++;
}
```

So it stays inside while loop and never exits from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant:

```
int j= 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

   while(j < 3)
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Then the `for` loop would execute 5 times and the `while` loop would execute a total of 10 times (twice for each time the `for` loop executes). It does not update in an alternating fashion. Instead, it stays inside the `while` loop until `j` is `3`. It then increments `i` and checks the `for` condition.